# IP addresses not updating, but showing correctly in the DHCP Address Leases

Tags: ip-address, dhcp

I first noticed this when I tried a `RDP` to a computer, **wxp-38-shop**, and it connected me to a different computer, **wxp-alvinm**.

I pinged **wxp-38-shop** and it shows a different IP than what is given in the Address Leases page (Windows 2003 Server). I tried to do `ipconfig /flushdns` on the server as well as the client computer, but it didn't update that way. If I do an `ipconfig` on the **wxp-38-shop** computer, it also shows `192.168.0.153`, the DHCP assigned lease.

So when I ping it from any other computer, why would it be showing the wrong IP?

Comment: I just noticed this is also causing Event ID 4 to appear in the log of the server:
The kerberos client received a KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED error from the server WXP-ALVINM$.  The target name used was cifs/WXP-38-SHOP.MacMachine.local. This indicates that the password used to encrypt the kerberos service ticket is different than that on the target server. Commonly, this is due to identically named  machine accounts in the target realm (MACMACHINE.LOCAL), and the client realm.   Please contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ipconfig /release and ipconfig /refresh on the clients? This forces the client to request a new IP lease from the DHCP server.

Comment: Yes I have tried the release and refresh. I confirmed from the computer that it did infact obtain a new IP, but when I ping that computer's name (wxp-38-shop) from the server, or any other computer it still shows as the old invalid IP. Of course the ping results time out because that IP no longer exists.

Comment: Then you should /flushdns on the computer you're trying the ping _from_, as this computer is keeping an old record of the hostname/ip combination.

Comment: You are right it does seem to be my computer that's keeping the old records. The strange thing is the server that assigns the DHCP addresses is also pinging the wrong IP address. Even though in DHCP Address Leases its showing the proper IP. I tried /flushdns on all computers (mine, the client, and the server) and I get the same results when pinging that computer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that IP Id from the Address lease. Restart the DHCP server and then your PC which is set to automatic detect IP Id in the LAN setting.